# How to attach SSL certificates in your network request flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl-certificate

I have 2 certificates

abc.bks

abc.p12

how do i attach these in my network request ,

as of now i am making request like this:

```
  final url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  final response = await http.get(url);

  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
  List<APIData> users = [];
  for (var u in jsonData) {
    APIData data = APIData(
        userId: u["userId"], id: u["id"], title: u["title"], body: u["body"]);
    users.add(data);
  }
```